# How to convert string to date data type

Tags: php, mysql, php-7.4

I want to save a date to my MySQL database but I get this error:

> user::__construct() must be an instance of date, string given

I tried to convert the result of my input type date to a timestamp using this line:

```
$myDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['birthdate']));
```

And I got this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: 2020-11-11
> user::__construct() must be an instance of date, null given

When I try to echo the data type of the variable $myDate it gives me String.

Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['surname']) and 
isset($_POST['birthdate']) and isset($_POST['email']) 
and isset($_POST['password'])){

//$myDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['birthdate']));
//echo $myDate;
//echo gettype($myDate);

$user1= new 
user($_POST['name'],$_POST['surname'],$_POST['birthdate'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);
$userCores= new userCores();
$userCores->addUser($user1);

//header('Location: showUser.php');

}
else 
{
echo "Missing fields" ; 
}
```

HTML:

```
              <form name="RegisterForm" method="POST" action="register.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nom">Nom <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="Entrer 
            votre nom" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="prenom">Prenom <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname"  
            placeholder="Entrer votre prenom" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="birthDate">date de naissance <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birthdate" name="birthdate"  
            placeholder="Entrer votre date de naissance" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"  placeholder="Entrer 
            votre email" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Mot de passe <sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" 
             placeholder="Mot de passe" >
            </div>
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-color w-100"  >Envoyer</button>
            
          </form>
```

PS: I'm using PHP 7.4 so here's my constructor:

```
private String $id;
private String $name;
private String $surname;
private date $birthdate;
private String $email;
private String $password;


function __construct(String $name, String $surname,date $birthdate, String $email,String $password){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->surname = $surname;
    $this->birthdate = $birthdate;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->password = $password;
}
```

(When I change the type to string and input type to text it works fine so I don't think that the problem is in my query).

Here's a screenshot when I pass a timestamp to the object

[image]

This screen when I pass the input type date

[image]

Comment: please show the content $_POST['birthdate']

Comment: It shows the date that i inserted in the input name="birthdate"

Comment: are you sure, please verify it, i would have guessed that it doesn't exist

Comment: See the screenshot in my post

Comment: the screenshot tells you clearly that it gets **NULL** instead if a date, as i already saud

Comment: i added an other capture when i pass the input value, Please read posts carfully next time.

Comment: ok now it is a stirng, still not  a date. but ui belive that is the $_POST not the $myDate

Comment: gettype($_POST['birthdate']) returns string, gettype($myDate) also returns string

Comment: @nbk it's clear that i'm using PHP OOP, in my constructor i did set the birthdate to be date type, so the object is expecting a date not a string. the issue is clear now?

Comment: i understood the problem right from the start, but i can't test it if DateTime::createFromFormat would work,, oo is maybe not the right aproach

Comment: Can you share the exact code triggering that problem? Also, how is this PHP error related to MySQL?

Comment: PHP doesn't have a class called `date` but it does have one called `DateTime`. Is this what you wanted? If so then you should create an instance of that class and pass that instead.

Answer (score -1):

try doing

```
$myDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['birthdate']));
```

instead of

```
$myDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['birthdate']));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns null in the object. : https://ibb.co/bLvXy2z